# richtextblock converting string to paragraph class

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, paragraph, richtextblock

I have a string filled as :

[string link](http://pastebin.com/AbFEa1xG)
(Sorry but I couldn't add XAML formatted text in this text editor.)

I wanna convert this string to Paragraph class in run-time. So I can add it simply in RichTextBlock.

How can I convert this string to paragraph format?
How can I do it

Comment: You have got a Broken link here

Comment: the link works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add some root element to the XAML so you can parse is as XML

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("<root>"+yourStringVariable+"</root>");
```

the go over the paragraphs and process them

```
var paragraphs = new List<Paragraph>();
foreach (var p in doc.Descendants("Paragraph"))
{
    var paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run {Text = p.Value});
}
```